# How to add custom fonts at all pages correctly in flutter

Tags: flutter

How to insert custom fonts? Code down below

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'constants.dart';
import 'pages/splash_page.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'School',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.orange),
        primaryColor: kPrimaryColor,
        primarySwatch: Colors.orange,
        useMaterial3: false,
      ),
      home: const SplashPage(),
    );
  }
}
```

I entered the name of the font I copied in pubspec.yaml and in assets, but the font does not change.

Comment: use fontName in TextStyle Like :-  Text(
              'School,
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 20.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontFamily: 'Poppins'),
            )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can add a global fontFamily inside ThemeData for all over the app**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'constants.dart';
import 'pages/splash_page.dart';
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
const MyApp({super.key});

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
    title: 'School',
    theme: ThemeData(
      fontFamily: 'fontname' //Montserrat
      colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.orange),
      primaryColor: kPrimaryColor,
      primarySwatch: Colors.orange,
      useMaterial3: false,
     ),
     home: const SplashPage(),
   );
  }
}
```

Please note that your font asset should be included in the pubspec.yaml

[image: example code to add fonts in pubspec.yaml file]